# Как в иде от Jet Brains исключить из поиска папку?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ide, jetbrains, rider

Пользуюсь Rider. Раньше было так правый клик -> exclude from search ну или что-то такое. Щас это пропало. Проблема даже не столько в поиске, сколько в том, когда нажимаешь Refactor -> Rename и Rider идет в js css бандлы чтоб что то переименовать. Это выедает кучу оперативной памяти (файлы огромные) все тормозит и падает. К тому же, мне совершенно не нужно ничего переименовывать в бандлах! Коллеги, подскажите, как просто тупо выкинуть несколько папок с бандлами скриптов и стилей из поиска и индексирования?

PS в тегах перечислю несколько иде, так как скорее всего, ответ не будет уникален для райдера.

Comment: ПКМ -> mark directory as -> excluded

Comment: @Moonvvell такого в контекстном меню нет. У меня райдер 2020.2.4. Я помню это еще по PhpStorm. Там было такой пункт. Сейчас почему-то в райдере его нет

Comment: Да, запустил - действительно нету. На оф. ютраке в 2017 создали таску. И ктото написал что тестируют новую систему и может в 2021.1 появится возможность.https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2173

Comment: @Moonvvell неплохо( Только вот щас работать стало почти невозможно без этого. Мне приходится удалять бандлы руками, чтоб он в них не искал.